# Why is my ajax submit not adding data to database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

When I submit form it doésn't add data to database or doesn't send mail. I have two form in one page. php code is okay. WhenI directly submit form to php page then it works. but via jquery code, it is not sending.

html code here

```
<div class="notify">
    <h2>Subscription Done! <span>x</span></h2>
</div>
<form id="formoid" action="subscribe.php" title="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nameid" id="nameid" placeholder="Name" required ><br>
    <input type="email" name="emailid" id="emailid" placeholder="Email" required ><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Subscribe Today">
</form>


<div id="contact">
        <a name="contact" style="padding-top: 100px;"></a>
        <h2 class="guide">CONTACT</h2>
        <form id="cont-form" method="post" action="processing.php">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Name"><br>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail"><br>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required placeholder="Subject"><br>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="10" cols="30" required placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="send">
        </form>
        <div id="cont-notify">
            <h2>Email Sent<span>x</span></h2>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is jquery code..

```
/*subscribe*/
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#formoid").submit(function(event) {
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();
  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $( this ),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );
  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { email: $('#emailid').val(), name: $('#nameid').val() } );
  /* Put the results in a div */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $("#formoid").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".notify").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".notify span").click(function(){
        $(".notify").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#formoid").fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
});


/*contact form*/
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#cont-form").submit(function(event) {
  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();
  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $( this ),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );
  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), subject: $('#subject').val(), message: $('#comments').val() } );
  /* Put the results in a div */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $("#cont-form").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#cont-notify").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#cont-notify span").click(function(){
        $("#cont-notify").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#cont-form").fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
});
```

It may be a hint..
http://ipartner.ca/idle/ jquery working in this page.
http://ipartner.ca/idle/processing.php jquery not working this page. couldn't find why..

Comment: Is your jQuery file and PHP file are in same folder?

Comment: Did both form failed? Or just the subscription form?

Comment: The name of the fields in your subscription form do not match the relevant javascript. In your subscription form, the name of the fields are "nameid" and "emailid". While the javascript form used "name" and "email".

Comment: For similar issues, I'd print values in the php, then use console.log in javascript to show the $.post respond data. It usually give you hints.

Comment: php file is in root folder and jquery is in a different folder. @prava

Comment: They are matching. please check, there are two form and code are different for both. @KoalaYeung

Comment: So, I guess you need to provide the absolute path for the URL `url = $form.attr( 'action' );`

Comment: So what is not working? Is he Ajax not posting? If php script failing some how? Can you narrow down the problem?

Comment: When the forms are submitted ajax isn't sending data probably. Both mailing and subscribe form not working. But when, I don't use ajax, it works. But I need to use ajax here. @MikeBrant